# Debian Testing, iwlwifi-7260 issue

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, wifi-driver, debian-jessie

I'm trying to install Debian Testing but I'm actually stuck in the wifi configuration. It asks for:

- iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
- iwlwifi-7260-14.ucode
- iwlwifi-7260-15.ucode
- iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode
- iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode

I found this files at https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/tree/master/firmware. As Debian asks, I put them in a USB drive and it appears that Debian accepts them, since installation goes ahead. But in fact wifi was not detected correctly, it didn't even shows the available networks.

In the other hand, I tried the same process with Debian Jessie. It asked for a different set of files:

- iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
- iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode

And surprisingly, it managed to detect wifi, presented available wifi networks and allowed me to select one.

Is there something I can do to help Debian Testing in the wifi configuration?

Answer (score 1):

The `iwlwifi` is a `non-free` firmware , you need to edit your `sources.list` by adding a non-free source , example:

```
deb http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free
```

To install the driver run the following command:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi
```